# Does Windows Azure support Silverlight Sockets

Tags: .net, silverlight, azure

Is it possible to open socket connections running on an Azure server from a Silverlight app.  If so, are their any examples

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit - December Update at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en
An example of a worker role listening on TCP/IP sockets is over there.

If the purpose is to have a web role opening socket connections to somewhere else: this can be done in the same manner you would do it on a regular, non-Azure app.